# Raphael JS sweeping clock

Tags: javascript, raphael

Using Raphael JS I want to have a continuing sweeping clock.

I have kind of got it implemented but there is a problem.

The transform on the animation constantly requries a increasing integer to rotate. Eventually I'm going to hit a max integer.

If I use 0,90,180,270. When it hits 0 again it goes back the other way.

CodePen ->
http://codepen.io/ianw92/pen/yNLdZz

Javascript:

```
var svg = Raphael("container",400,400),
    triangle = svg.path("M210 200L190 200L200 100Z").attr({fill:"#000"}),
    circle = svg.circle(200,200,5).attr({fill:"#f00"});

// Rotation settings
var handAngle = 45,
    centerX = 200,
    centerY = 200;

y = 0

function a() {
    y = (y + 90) % 360;
    triangle.animate({transform: "r"+y + "," + centerX + "," + centerY}, 500, b);
}
function b() {
    y = (y + 90) % 360;
    triangle.animate({transform: "r"+y + "," + centerX + "," + centerY}, 500, a);
}

a()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key was to use Raphael.animation(...).repeat(Infinity)

http://codepen.io/ianw92/pen/xGbKJq

```
var anim=Raphael.animation({transform: "r360" + "," + centerX + "," + centerY}, 60000, 'linear').repeat(Infinity);

triangle.animate(anim);
```